# Does buying the Treasure Map cancel the Curse of Darkness Curse?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I'm doing my first [challenge](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Challenges) run in The Binding of Isaac and I've decided to do the the first challenge on the list: **Dark was the Night.** This is the challenge where you automatically have the Curse of Darkness on all floors.

In this run I came across a shop selling the Treasure Map item.
This item "Reveals all rooms for every floor, including the Secret Room. However, it does not reveal icons."(from the [wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Shop))

Which ability has priority?  The curse or the map?  Will I be able to see the map again?  Or will it be a waste of 15 pennys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Purchasing the Treasure Map in the Dark was the Night challenge will not override the Curse of Darkness**
As seen in the screen shot of me buying the map below, the map will not show any rooms.  The Curse of Darkness has priority over the map.  It is just a waste of 15 pennys.

[image: dat face]